# Yarn.lock does not update after upgrading dependency with yarn add?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I upgraded one of my packages by using `npm i @pulumi/akamai@latest`, and I see the updated devDependency in my project's `package.json`, with the code below.

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@pulumi/akamai": "^1.0.0",
         .....other dependencies
}
```

However my `yarn.lock` file is unchanged, with

```
"@pulumi/akamai@^0.1.0":
  version "0.1.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@pulumi/akamai/-/akamai-0.1.0.tgz#e6eed04448670719fd4fbc3df06023c0b61b780b"
  integrity sha512-Zs44yZrULrBMEA3ezb/A4baVX3cNQlE2+yrBBR75SfkK1TmhqitarEWnM1/JOQ/z7EIJZJN8SdqE5hsvXf/ssA==
  dependencies:
    "@pulumi/pulumi" "^2.0.0
```

I've tried running `yarn`, `yarn install`, and `yarn add @pulumi/akamai@latest`, but none of these commands are updating my `yarn.lock`. How can I update the `yarn.lock` file?

Comment: Why would `npm i[nstall]` update *Yarn's* lock file? That should update `package-lock.json`, but if you have both you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: why wouldn't `yarn add @pulumi/akamai@latest` update `yarn.lock`?

Comment: I'd expect `yarn add` *would*, but you open with asking why `npm i` doesn't. Please [edit] to give a [mre] focusing on something that *might* work.